# Does STL bitset support value fields?

Tags: c++, stl, bit-manipulation

Currently, I am using bit fields to represent a register of flags in c++:

```
struct DEVICE_REGISTER  {
     unsigned ready:1;        // 1 if device is ready
     unsigned error:1;        // 1 if an error occurred.
     unsigned bus_address:4;  // up to 16 possible drives on bus
     unsigned command:2;      // up to 4 different commands
     unsigned error_code:8;
};
```

Performing bitwise operations is clean, easy and intuitive:

```
{
    dev_reg->bus_address = 1;
    dev_reg->command = CmdReset;

    /* wait until operation done, ready will be true */

    while ( ! dev_reg->ready ) ;

    /* check for errors */

    if (dev_reg->error)
      { /* interrogate disk_reg->error_code for error type */
        switch (dev_reg->error_code)
        ......
      }
}
```

I would like to use STL's `bitset<>` for it's efficiency, however, but I can't find out how to declare a segment of bits as data fields referenced by name.  The following obviously won't work:

```
struct DEVICE_REGISTER  {
     bitset<1> ready;        // 1 if device is ready
     bitset<1> error;        // 1 if an error occurred.
     bitset<4> bus_address;  // up to 16 possible drives on bus
     bitset<2> command;      // up to 4 different commands
     bitset<8> error_code;
};

if (dev_reg->error_code)
     dev_reg->error_code = 0; // clear the error codes
     dev_reg->error = 0;
     resend(dev_reg);  // resend the register 
};
```

If `bitset<>` doesn't support this capability, then I have a difficult time seeing any real benefit in using it. What you gain in having a more compact data structure, you lose in code bulk, complexity, readability and reliability. Referring to values by their position and size rather than by a named fields is prone to human error and requires lots of code gymnastics.

Comment: The std::bitset is not a bit field. It abstracts away bit access and nothing more. 
C bit fields are a nice feature as long as you don't want to have any guarantees about size, alignment or padding inside the bit field across different implementations.

Comment: `bitset` is not even remotely a replacement for bit fields. The two have nothing in common but the word "bit" in their names. As but one demonstration, check `sizeof(DEVICE_REGISTER)` of the two definitions - that might prove illuminating.

Comment: So this is all a big fraud?  Nothing new for MCU programmers?  Can I at least convert a bitfield to a bitset like Bitset<16>(dev_reg) and use it to serialize the bits for IO? Perhaps, it will pack the bits correctly.